# React: Preserve cookies when redirecting to sub-domain

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-router, session-cookies

I need to redirect a user after successful auth to its own sub-domain like

`company.test.com` from `test.com`

The auth page opens on `test.com` and when I get response for successful auth I get the user's sub-domain name from the database. So company name `xyz` should redirect to `xzy.test.com`, **That part is already done**.

The issue is the session of the user. I am saving the authenticated user data into redux and when pages refreshes/redirects to the subdomain it loses the user data.

All I can think of is that I should pass the authenticated user `id` along with sub-domain like `xyz.test.com/encrypted-user-id` to a route and I will get that user id on the back-end and will decrypt it and will force user login without asking for password again.

**My question is that... is there an alternate way? If no, Is this a feasible way to solve this**

Comment: Try cross domain localStorage to achieve, here is the link  https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternate, and more *correct* way to solve your question.

I'll try to answer in two parts: first enabling cookies between root- and sub-domains, and second how to do this in Laravel.

**Make cookies available between root and sub-domains**:

When receiving cookie headers, a browser can be instructed to share the cookie across subdomains. This is achieved by adding the domain to the `Set-Cookie` header.

```
Set-Cookie: user=JohnDoe; domain=testdomain.com
```

As of [RFC-6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), the above syntax will tell the browser that cookies set on `test.com` should be made available to all subdomains (i.e. `a.test.com`, `xyz.test.com`). For a more detailed explanation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/590848) here on SO.

**Set cookies to be available on subdomains in Laravel**:

According to [Laravel `responses` documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses) the `cookie` function accepts all arguments accepted by php's `[setcookie][4]` function (look at `path` and `domain` arguments).

As an example, for a *one off* you could write:

```
$path = '/'; // make cookie available on all paths
$domain = "test.com";  // according to rfc6265 make available on root and subdomains
return $response($content)->cookie($name, $value, $minutes, $path, $domain);
```

Another way, for **sharing all cookies** across the root and subdomains comes from [JacobBennet's snippet](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/15558410de2a394373ac). The suggestion there is to set the desired value of the `domain` variable in `config/session.php`. Then, **all (!)** cookies will be available to subdomains.

The frontend side (React) should not do anything particular, besides "redirecting".